# Now that we have Honeycomb, what is RenderScript?

Tags: android, 3d, android-3.0-honeycomb, renderscript

So Android 3.0 (honeycomb) is out now and [boasts](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.0-highlights.html) some kind of new hardware-accelerated 3D graphics engine called Renderscript.

> **Renderscript 3D graphics engine**
>
> Renderscript is a runtime 3D framework that provides both an API for building 3D scenes as well as a special, platform-independent shader language for maximum performance. Using Renderscript, you can accelerate graphics operations and data processing. Renderscript is an ideal way to create high-performance 3D effects for applications, wallpapers, carousels, and more.

And according to this blog [post](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/11/android-renderscript-more-info-and.html) dating back from 2009, this graphics engine could already be found used in a class named Fountain (even before honeycomb). This last clue was helpful to me, because now I can easily find that [class name](http://www.andrada-dev.org/android-sdk-mac_x86/samples/android-Honeycomb/RenderScript/Fountain/src/com/android/fountain/) in the Honeycomb code.

Can any of you supply any more insights into Renderscript? and ways to learn more about how to use it? Now that this has become a public api, I'm assuming that the people in-the-know may be able to get the permission to freely talk about it (I hope).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you downloaded the Honeycomb SDK via the android tool? It downloads documentation, including the javadoc pages for Renderscript.

Comment: Actually no, I hadn't. I feel silly for not doing that. I'll do that right now, and report back. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

RenderScript is several things:
- A language, similar to C99 with extra advanced features. It's pre-compiled on the host and re-compiled on the device, to achieve best performance.
- A rendering library (you can draw textured meshes, etc.)
- A compute library (to run heavy computations in RenderScript which can then be offloaded to the GPU, several CPUs or DSPs.)